# Are the existential dangers of AI exaggerated?

Tags: ethics, superintelligence, ai-safety, deepfakes, algorithmic-bias

I understand some of the inherent dangers involved with AGI and advanced machine learning. While I can see some of the more low-level risks associated with AI coming to fruition (deep-fakes, biased algorithms, etc.), some of the more existential dangers seem far-fetched and lack empirical examples. As someone outside of AI development circles and without a background in comp-sci, I would like to know how realistic those working in the field of AI find these fears. Are there any convincing hypotheticals about the risks of a superintelligence?

I've read some Stuart Russel and have recently been watching Robert Miles videos on the topic. Both of these observers seem worried. Is this opinion widely held or is it seen as a bit extreme among developers?

[Provably Beneficial Artificial Intelligence](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Erussell/papers/russell-bbvabook17-pbai.pdf)
by *Stuart Russell*

[Robert Miles YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLB7AzTwc6VFZrBsO2ucBMg)

Comment: We have had similar questions in the past. For example, [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/4037/2444), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1824/2444), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/15449/2444), etc. Your question is very related to (or a duplicate of) [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/7875/2444), which has some good answers, in my view, but it focuses on "the emergence of superintelligence" rather than "existential dangers". Having said that, I think we can all agree that Stuart Russell is an expert in AI (or, at least, on some AI topics). He's the co-author of the AIMA book.